# All frames from Kinect at 30FPS

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using Microsoft Kinect SDK and I would like to know whether it is possible to get Depth Frame, Color Frame as well as the skeleton data for all the frames at 30fps? Using Kinect Explorer I can see that the color and the depth frame are nearly at 30fps, but as soon as I choose the view the skeleton, it drops to around 15-20fps.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on [Gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Detecting the skeleton is CPU intensive. What's your computer configuration?

Comment: This question is better asked here.  The Kinect community is not nearly as active over at Gamedev.

Comment: @IanMedeiros: Core2Duo 2Ghz 64bit Windows 8 Pro 2GB RAM. That means that if I have to get color and depth frames, it can be guaranteed to be at 30fps, but for the skeleton it depends on the CPU and CPU usage?

Comment: You have a rock age computer. That's why you can't handle it at 30FPS. You need a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to capture color/depth at 30fps while capturing the skeleton.

See image below, just in case you think me dodgy. :)  This is a raw Kinect Explorer running, straight from Visual Studio 2010.  My work development platform is an i5 Dell laptop.

[image: 30fps Kinect Explorer]

Comment: I tried the same thing, but for me it gives around 15-20 fps with the skeleton. I guess that is because of my CPU configuration?
Core2Duo 2Ghz 64bit Windows 8 Pro 2GB RAM.

Comment: I would imagine your computer is straining under the load.  With an upgraded CPU it will likely perform much better.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey what can be the minimum configuration for the " upgraded cpu" ? I am also facing this problem