# Kinect Skeleton FPS

Tags: c++, kinect

I am using 'Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.8'. For skeleton tracking I calculated the FPS and it is about 10-15. Does 'Microsoft' provide any spesifications? I would like to increase the FPS for skeleton frame data, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

See this article : [All frames from Kinect at 30FPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978415/all-frames-from-kinect-at-30fps) .

Your computer decides the skeleton frame rate .

If you want to control the frame rate . You can set a timer to do this .

use SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame Method and timer to control FPS.

In XNA , you can also control the frame rate by using a timer.

the other article : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56e90644-98fd-4224-9210-02e10f290a70/skeleton-frame-rate?forum=kinectsdknuiapi